# Product exchange Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to implement Product exchange functionality where in case customer order for wrong color/size, he can request for correct one to admin.

In this case, I would like to let admin change status of that product from **Shipped** to let's call **Exchanged** and then admin can put new order on behalf of customer for correct product.

[image]

I am not able to find code to change order item status. I can find code to change Order status but that's not required in this case.

Any idea how to do this? or any easier way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have RMA (for Return Management) Plugin for managing such kinds of returns and exchange. You can get RMA extension for Magento 2 from here https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-rma-extension.html [For now its free ;) ]

The process would be:

> 1. Order Placed by customer and fulfilled by merchandise.
> 2. Customer can raise a request to return or exchange full or partial products from the order.
> 3. Admin can authorise the request(Approve or Reject).
> 4. On Receiving Product Inventor will get updated & now new order can be placed by the admin.

Hope it finds helpful.